# R - aggregate create strange size of dataset after store

Tags: r, aggregate

When I try to make a statistics using aggregate with below data - as a example - 
strange size of output was stored

```
        group    O18        D
    1   st1    -6.89    -53.52709
    2   st1    -7.16    -56.75802
    3   st1    -7.17    -54.79471
    4   st2    -7.09    -54.98376
    5   st2    -7.02    -54.56050
    6   st2    -6.99    -55.55472
```

command I used was:

```
statistic <- aggregate(. ~ group, data=dt, FUN = function(x) 
                       c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)))
```

And output: 'statistic (2 obs. of 3 variables)' was stored as ;

```
    group       O18          D
1   st1     -7.07333333 -55.0266058
2   st2     -7.03333333 -55.0329908
3            0.15885003  1.6278974
4            0.05131601  0.4989327
```

But when I entered just

```
aggregate(. ~ group, data=dt, FUN = function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)))
```

below was printed

```
  group    O18.mean      O18.sd      D.mean        D.sd
1   st1 -7.07333333  0.15885003 -55.0266058   1.6278974
2   st2 -7.03333333  0.05131601 -55.0329908   0.4989327
```

I want to get the Second output as **stored dataset**, not just printed 
In first output, the size of dataset is defined as 2*3 ,even though there are 3th and 4th row, I can't use the sd values

Comment: Yes, it's exactly same code except defining 
I can not make a data array when I stored 
Is there anyone have had same problem? or did I miss something?

Comment: @Khashaa, sorry - what did you mean?

Comment: Try converting to data.frame i.e. `do.call(data.frame, statistic)`. as there are only three variables in `statistic`, 2nd and 3rd column are matrices.  Though, I couldn't reproduce the problem in `R 3.1.2`

Comment: @JinaJeong Have you tried `do.call(data.frame, aggregate(. ~ group, data=dt, FUN = function(x) 
                       c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))))`

Comment: What do you call a "stored dataset"?

Comment: Weird. If I call `View(output)` I get the first output, but if I just call `output` itself, I get the second result. Similarly, if I call `names(output)` i get the names from the first result. Anyone have any reason why?
Anyway, this is pretty straight forward with dplyr:
`output <- dt %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(O18mean = mean(O18), O18sd = sd(O18), Dmean = mean(D), Dsd = sd(D)) `

Comment: @goodtimeslim What is `output`? `statistic`?

Comment: Sorry, `output` is what I called the initial data, I guess what @JinaJeong called `statistic`. The second `outout` (the dplyr version) is what I believe she wants.

Comment: Right, I guess the issue is that in the original call, the aggregate function is returning a vector instead of single values, and that's getting things a little jumbled up. I just wanted to show the dplyr version because I think that's a little more straight forward, but maybe that's just because I use dplyr a lot.

Comment: @akrun It's succeed with do.call(data.frame, aggregate(. ~ group, data=dt, FUN = function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))))!! Thanks a lot
And also thanks for other comments, everyone !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we use `aggregate` with multiple function results concatenated (`c(mean=mean(x), sd=...)`), columns in the result will be coerced to `matrix`.  Thus, the `View(output)` shows a different format than expected.  One possible option would be change the `matrix` format of some columns by calling `data.frame` again.

```
output <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(. ~ group, data=dt,
         FUN = function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))))

 str(output)
 #'data.frame': 2 obs. of  5 variables:
 #$ group   : Factor w/ 2 levels "st1","st2": 1 2
 #$ O18.mean: num  -7.07 -7.03
 #$ O18.sd  : num  0.1589 0.0513
 #$ D.mean  : num  -55 -55
 #$ D.sd    : num  1.628 0.499
```

This would not be a problem if you use `dplyr` or `data.table` solutions

```
 library(dplyr)
 output1 <- dt %>% 
              group_by(group) %>% 
              summarise_each(funs(mean, sd))
 str(output1)
 #Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  5 variables:
 #$ group   : chr  "st1" "st2"
 #$ O18_mean: num  -7.07 -7.03
 #$ D_mean  : num  -55 -55
 #$ O18_sd  : num  0.1589 0.0513
 #$ D_sd    : num  1.628 0.499
 #- attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE
```